# Get the number of rows in a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I've browsed the Internet looking for an answer on this but I can't find a solution. I want to count the amount of rows my HTML table has in when a link button is pressed. Can someone help me out please?

This is what I have so far:

```
 $('#HypSelectAll').click(function () {
     var count = $('#gvPerformanceResult').children().length;
     for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        alert(i);
     }
 });
```

But some reason it returns 0 even though I have about 12 rows in my table? I've checked my ID name and it's correct.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try:

```
var count = $('#gvPerformanceResult tr').length;
```

Comment: Note that this will not give the expected result with nested tables, i.e. tables that contain other tables.

Answer (score 95):

```
var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
```

Comment: Is there a way to subset this to rows meeting a certain condition?

Answer (score 6):

> The following code assumes that your table has the ID 'MyTable'
>
> ```
> <script language="JavaScript">
> <!--
> var oRows = document.getElementById('MyTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');
> var iRowCount = oRows.length;
>
> alert('Your table has ' + iRowCount + ' rows.');
> //-->
> </script>
> ```

Answer taken from : http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/f771.shtml, which is the first result on google for the query : "Get the number of rows in a HTML table" ;)

Comment: For my own personal knowledge, what is not cross browser in this solution ?

Comment: getElementsByTagName varies somewhat from IE, FF and (Chrome, Webkit, Opera) 
IE7/8 have a habit of returning 0 for your example.
Firefox can get confused with namespaces.
In the later doesnt support the same style of namespaces.

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=248215
http://webbugtrack.blogspot.co.uk/2007/09/bug-204-getelementsbytagname-doesnt.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536439(v=vs.85).aspx (comments)

I'd avoid getElementsByTagName.

Answer (score 5):

In the DOM, a `tr` element is (implicitly or explicitly) a child of `tbody`, `thead`, or `tfoot`, not a child of `table` (hence the 0 you got). So a general answer is:

```
var count = $('#gvPerformanceResult > * > tr').length;
```

This includes the rows of the table but excludes rows of any inner table.

Comment: Or you can use : `var count = $('#gvPerformanceResult tr').length;`

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what you have in your table.

its one of the following
If you have only one table

```
var count = $('#gvPerformanceResult tr').length;
```

If you are concerned about sub tables but this wont work with tbody and thead (if you use them)

```
var count = $('#gvPerformanceResult>tr').length;
```

Where by this will work (but is quite frankly overkill.)

```
var count = $('#gvPerformanceResult>tbody>tr').length;
```

Comment: The second selector won't work at all.